# Spring hibernate orderBy on list element

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

```
@Entity
class Person{
   private int id;
   @OneToMany(mappedBy=owner)
   private List<Pet> pets;
}

@Entity
class Pet{
  private name;
  private ZonedDateTime birthDate;
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="owner_id")
  private Person owner;
}
```

I want to find all the persons and order them by their oldest pet birthday

**The only way I can solve this is through @Formula** , something like

```
@Entity
class Person{
   private int id;
   private List<Pet> pets;

   @Formula("(SELECT p.birth_date FROM pet p WHERE p.owner_id = id order by p.birth_date ASC LIMIT 1)")
   private ZonedDateTime oldestPetBirthday;
}
```

then

```
public List<Person> findPersonByOrderByOldestPetBirthdayAsc
```

But **I don't want to touch raw sql**, I am looking for something like

```
public List<Person> findPersonByOrderByPetsTop1OrderByBirthDateAsc
```

OR by using pageable something like:

```
PageRequest.of(page,pageSize,Sort.by(ASC, "pets.sort(BirthDateComparator).get(0)"))
```

is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `@OrderBy` annotation from `@javax.persistence.OrderBy` package on your one to many collection object.

```
@OrderBy("birthDate")
private List<Pet> pets;
```

Comment: I don't want to hard code it into the entity

Comment: Then write your own comparator or use Collections.sort method which takes collection and comparator as an argument

Comment: that wont work if you fetch x top element or try to use paging, because the sort will happen after the query execution.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution with the formula is ok but suffers from some issues. Anyway, since you don't want to write SQL, you will have to use something like [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Person.class)
public interface PersonDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    @Limit(limit = "1", order = "birthDate desc)
    @Mapping("pets")
    OldestPetDto getOldestPet();

    @EntityView(Pet.class)
    interface OldestPetDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        ZonedDateTime getBirthDate();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`PersonDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, PersonDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<PersonDto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!

Also, you can add a `Sort` for `oldestPet.birthDate` and it will work just like you would like it to!